# Passing Instance Method to Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, instance

I want to run two methods from another class simultaneously. Obviously, the code below will not work. How can I do something like this?

```
Node node = new Node();
EHNode ehnode = new EHNode();

Thread normalNode = new Thread(node.RunNode());
Thread ehNode = new Thread(ehnode.RunNode());

normalNode.Start();
ehNode.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

```
Node node = new Node();
EHNode ehnode = new EHNode();

Thread normalNode = new Thread(new ThreadStart(node.RunNode));
Thread ehNode = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ehnode.RunNode));

normalNode.Start();
ehNode.Start();
```